# View binding Vs Data binding in Android

Tags: android

Android documentation says that View binding is a feature whereas Data binding is a library. What does that mean? Is there any relation between the binding classes generated from View binding and Data binding? Do they generate a single binding class or separate?

```
{
    viewBinding = true
    dataBinding = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I came to know that View Binding and Data Binding both generate a single binding class.

Example:
Suppose we have a layout file activity_main.xml and if you enable view binding in module-level build.gradle file, an ActivityMainBinding.java file will be generated inside the build > generated folders hierarchy.
Now, if we enable data binding as well and make changes inside the XML layout file(adding a layout tag and including our view model), the same file ActivityMainBinding.java automatically undergoes some changes inside it and serves both view binding and data binding purposes.

Answer (score 3):

They generate separate classes, because they do totally separate things.

View binding generates a binding class to be used in code.  You use it when you inflate views, and it goes through the inflated view and populates a field for each view with an id, named with the name of the id.  It allows you not to do all the `View x = findViewById(R.id.y)` stuff and replace all of that with a single binding.

Data binding creates classes that can be referenced in your layout xml and used to automatically move data from that binding class into the views.  For example, you can say a TextView's text is {user.name} and when you update the model for that layout it will automatically populate the view with the new value.

Data binding is a bit controversial-  some people love it, some hate it. It's a major change in how you do things.  View Binding is basically a replacement for ButterKnife and a small quality of life improvement for developers.

Comment: Data binding works well with MVVM projects, passing in the view model as the variable and then allowing you to define text fields, button states, on click functions, inversely bound edit text and spinner values, etc. through live data and view model methods.  Maybe overkill for something simple, but when the view classes become sufficiently complex, I find it nice to move boilerplate to the xml.

Comment: @MattGrier And I prefer xml to be pure layout and views, I find mixing the logic and the views like that leads to incomprehensible code where you need to check a dozen places to figure out what's actually happening. It reminds me of all the worst things about PHP and early perl based webapps.   Some people love it, some hate it.  Thus why I said "controversial".

Comment: @MattGrier Sorry if this is a silly question......you mean they generate separate classes with same names?

Comment: In the project I am working on right now, which has view binding and data binding,  under java -> generated -> databinding , there is one file per layout.  You can either wrap your xml in a <layout></layout> tag and provide objects to bind (with data binding = true) or just use viewBinding.  @GabeSechan on something simple I guess I agree with you, the separation of: pure xml and logic in the view classes makes sense.  But with large complex classes to refactor, I am liking defining the data in a ViewModel (and the click methods) and just setting them in xml.

Comment: @GabeSechan Do you agree with my last comment?

Comment: @GabeSechan Sorry to say but I am not able to find the separate classes generated as a result of View Binding + Data Binding in my Android Project. There is only one autogenerated class named ActivityMainBinding.java (for a layout file activity_main.xml) which I can find under build > generated > data_binding_base_class_source_out folder. The interesting part is that I can access my views and the variable used inside <data> tag for DataBinding with the same reference type i.e. ActivityMainBinding.java

Comment: @AnonymousCodes Did you declare a model class in any of your xml classes?  If not, nothing will be generated.  The class you're talking about is the ViewBinding class.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I have used a model class inside the XML layout and am able to access the views (like if its for view binding) as well as the model declared inside it. Also, as I have said before that I am using the same class reference to access all the data whether its related to view binding OR data binding.